# what is the difference between movie/film and theater?

Tags: cinema, theater

what is difference between movie/film and theater?. Do these differences make movies "better" than theater,or simply "different"?

thank you for your answer:)))

Comment: You can watch a movie or a film in a theater. You can also watch a play in a theater. I don't understand how that would make a theater "better" than a movie (or a play?) I eat a meal in a reatarant. Does that make meals "better" than a restaurant, or "different"?

Comment: Have you looked these words up in a dictionary.  If not, please do so, and ***then*** if you still have a question about this, please explain it in more detail.  You may find that the English Language Learners site at http://ell.stackexchange.com/ is more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[theater](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/theatre) - the art or activity of writing and performing plays, or the public performance of plays. Also a play or other activity or presentation considered in terms of its dramatic quality.

[movie](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/movie?q=Movie)/[film](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/film?q=Film) -  In general, a story or event recorded by a camera as a set of moving images and shown in a cinema or on television.

To sum up, you watch both a theater and a movie/film, but a theater is enacted on a stage in front of an audience and watched live whereas a cinema/film is watched on a screen which displays the the recorded and edited version.

Comment: Yes, in Britain whilst a film (movie) is watched in a *cinema*, *theatres* are for stage productions. The only exception I know of here is *The National Film Theatre* on the South Bank in London which shows very high quality films that you are unlikely to find in the normal commercial cinema.